# suffering with errors with readonly

Tags: c#

I have a problem when trying to access a readonly field in a class of constants through an object from another class

Constant class :

```
class iec_104_data_constants
{
    public readonly byte[] STARTDTcon= {0x68, 0x04, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; 
    public readonly byte[] STOPDTcon = {0x68, 0x04, 0x23, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; 
    public readonly byte[] TESTFRcon = {0x68, 0x04, 0x83, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};                    
    public readonly byte[] nothing = {}; 
}



class iec104_class
{
    iec_104_data_constants c = new iec_104_data_constants();

    public static byte[] construct_SU_frames(byte[] dequeud_frame) 
    {

        if (dequeud_frame[2] == 0x07) // STARTDTact
            return c.STARTDTcon;
        if (dequeud_frame[2] == 0x13) //STOPDTact
            return c.STOPDTcon;
        if (dequeud_frame[2] == 0x43) //STOPDTact
            return c.STOPDTcon;
        else
            return c.Nothing;
    }
```

Error:

> Error  CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'iec104_class.c'

Comment: `c` needs to be static.

Comment: Make filed `c` static: `private static iec_104_data_constants c = new iec_104_data_constants();`

Comment: static methods cannot access none static members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `construct_SU_frames` is `static`, but you declared `c` to be an *instance* member.

Declare `c` as static and it should work:

```
class iec104_class
{
    // make it STATIC
    static iec_104_data_constants c = new iec_104_data_constants();

    //...
}
```